# Flatten a tree (list of lists) with one statement?

Tags: .net, tree, flatten

Thanks to nHibernate, some of the data structures I work with are lists within lists within lists. So for example I have a data object called "category" which has a .Children property that resolves to a list of categories ... each one of which can have children ... and so on and so on.

I need to find a way of starting at a top-level category in this structure and getting a list or array or something similar of all the children in the entire structure - so all the children of all the children etc etc, flattened into a single list.

I'm sure it can be done with recursion, but I find recursive code a pain to work through, and I'm convinced there must be a more straightforward way in .Net 4 using Linq or somesuch - any suggestions?

Comment: Flattening a tree seems inherently recursive.  I don't believe there is a single statement way to flatten a tree, even with LINQ.  Would you accept a recursive answer?

Comment: Certainly. It's just one of those things that seems like there should be an "easy" answer. Linq "selectMany" will flatten two levels of a tree, but the trouble is that I have no way of knowing how many levels I've got in my object when I start. So I guess recursion is the only way to go.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming your Category class looks something like:

```
 public class Category
 {
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<Category> Children { get; set; }
 }
```

I don't think there's an "easy" non-recursive way to do it; if you're simply looking for a single method call to handle it, the "easy" way is to write the recursive version into a single method call. There's probably an iterative way to do this, but I'm guessing it's actually pretty complicated. It's like asking the "easy" way to find a tangent to a curve without using calculus.

Anyway, this would probably do it:

```
public static List<Category> Flatten(Category root) {

    var flattened = new List<Category> {root};

    var children = root.Children;

    if(children != null)
    {
        foreach (var child in children)
        {
            flattened.AddRange(Flatten(child));
        }
    }

    return flattened;
}
```

Comment: There *is* an easy non-recursive solution, but it does a breadth-first traversal (see my answer). That's probably not a big issue, but it depends on what the OP wants exactly...

Answer (score 40):

Here's an extension method that does the job:

```
// Depth-first traversal, recursive
public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source,
        Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childrenSelector)
{
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        yield return item;
        foreach (var child in childrenSelector(item).Flatten(childrenSelector))
        {
            yield return child;
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
foreach(var category in categories.Flatten(c => c.Children))
{
    ...
}
```

The solution above does a depth-first traversal, if you want a breadth-first traversal you can do something like this:

```
// Breadth-first traversal, non-recursive
public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten2<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source,
        Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childrenSelector)
{
    var queue = new Queue<T>(source);
    while (queue.Count > 0)
    {
        var item = queue.Dequeue();
        yield return item;
        foreach (var child in childrenSelector(item))
        {
            queue.Enqueue(child);
        }
    }
}
```

It also has the benefit of being non-recursive...

---

UPDATE: Actually, I just thought of a way to make the depth-first traversal non-recursive... here it is:

```
// Depth-first traversal, non-recursive
public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten3<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source,
        Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childrenSelector)
{
    LinkedList<T> list = new LinkedList<T>(source);
    while (list.Count > 0)
    {
        var item = list.First.Value;
        yield return item;
        list.RemoveFirst();
        var node = list.First;
        foreach (var child in childrenSelector(item))
        {
            if (node != null)
                list.AddBefore(node, child);
            else
                list.AddLast(child);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using a `LinkedList<T>` because insertions are O(1) operations, whereas insertions to a `List<T>` are O(n).

Comment: +1 for cleverness on the queue-based solution. I don't know that I'd call it "easy", but then I guess that's a matter of opinion. And the breadth v. depth -first question is an important one; I tend to assume depth-first, and that's a bad habit to get into. Anyway, your answer is better.

Comment: Regarding depth first: Adding "if (source == null) yield break;" would fit most use-cases

Answer (score 1):

If breadth-first traversal is OK and you only want to use some short non-recursive inline code (3 lines actually), create a list initialized with your root element(s) and then extend it by just one simple for-loop:

```
// your data object class looks like:
public class DataObject
{
  public List<DataObject> Children { get; set; }
  ...
}

...

// given are some root elements
IEnumerable<DataObject> rootElements = ...

// initialize the flattened list with the root elements
var result = new List<DataObject>(rootElements);
// extend the flattened list by one simple for-loop, 
// please note that result.Count may increase after every iteration!
for (int index = 0; index < result.Count; index++)
  result.AddRange(result[index].Children);
```

Comment: What if your tree is more than 1 deep? This won't work.

Comment: @rolls The list extends itself while being looped. This way it will traverse all elements on all levels.

Comment: That is clever I missed that. I believe if you use a linked-list the AddRange will be more performant as well.

Comment: @rolls Thanks for your hint. I added a comment to show that there's a little trick here. Unfortunately the LinkedList has no AddRange method so I used the List class to keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

Given the class @E.Z.Hart mentions, you could also extend it with a helper method for this which I think is simpler in this case.

```
public class Category
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Category> Children { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Category> AllChildren()
    {
        yield return this;
        foreach (var child in Children)
        foreach (var granChild in child.AllChildren())
        {
            yield return granChild;
        }
    }   
}
```